# How to access delegated mailbox using Python without win32.client

Tags: python, linux, email, delegates, imap

I have a windows account with a mailbox. 
Using Python on a Linux environment, I can access any mail and directory from the mailbox using imaplib the account credentials so that's fine.

But now, I want to access a delegated mailbox that is not belonging to this account and can't find how.

So far I used this code from doc that gives all the directories within the mailbox. Now I'd like to reach another mailbox.

I tried to change the username by username/delegated-mailbox but connection fails.

I've seen some solutions on windows environment using win32.client, but so far, nothing on linux. Is there a solution using imaplib or another lib?

```
import imaplib
import ConfigParser


def open_connection(verbose=False):
  # Read the config file
  config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
  config.read('connection.cfg')

  # Connect to the server
  hostname = config.get('server', 'hostname')
  if verbose: print 'Connecting to', hostname
  connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(hostname)

  # Login to our account
  username = config.get('account', 'username')
  password = config.get('account', 'password')
  if verbose: print 'Logging in as', username
  connection.login(username, password)
  return connection


c = open_connection(verbose=True)
try:
    typ, mailbox_data = c.list()
    for line in mailbox_data:
        print line     
finally:
    try:
        c.close()
    except:
        pass
    c.logout()
```

Config file is like:

```
[server]
hostname: the.hostname

[account]
username: test-account
password: test-password
```

Comment: What is the server software?

Comment: Sorry, it's on a RedHat 6.8, Python 2.7.11 and IMAPClient 1.0.2

Comment: No, what is the IMAP Server software.  "windows mailbox" could mean anything.

Comment: Yes, this is Microsoft Exchange